# importXML Xpath query, <div> tags inside <div> in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: html, xpath, spreadsheet, google-docs

I'm using Xpath in Google docs to get the text inside `<div>.` I want to save the text inside `<div class="sc-fbNXWD iBmpVC">` in one cell of Google doc spreadsheet, but it shows each `<div>` in separate cell.

```
<div class="sc-GTWni glMBCA">
<div class="sc-fbNXWD iBmpVC">BOT Price</div>
<div class="sc-fbNXWD iBmpVC">
    <div font-size="18px" color="text" class="sc-gsTCUz VFvYA" style="line-height: 1;">$1.480</div>
</div>
```

May you help me to put data in only one cell ?
i nedd query 1.480, i try `//div[@class='sc-fbNXWD iBmpVC']` but not work.
[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAkZ.png)

Comment: What xpath expression did you try so far?

Comment: try //div[@class='sc-fbNXWD iBmpVC']/text()

Comment: To get a better understanding of your problem, I suggest to share more html or even better the url to the html. I suspect the classes you are showing, could be randomly generated.